# Get list of ranks between a range

Tags: mysql

I got a table which looks like this:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+
| Username(varchar) | Points(integer) |
+-------------------+---------------------+
| User #0           |                1000 |
| User #1           |                 900 |
| User #2           |                 900 |
| User #3           |                 810 |
| User #4           |                 800 |
| User #5           |                 790 |
| User #6           |                 750 |
| User #7           |                 749 |
| User #8           |                 730 |
| User #9           |                 650 |
| User #10          |                 600 |
| User #11          |                 550 |
| User #12          |                 450 |
+-------------------+---------------------+
```

I need a query where I can put 2 numbers in. For example I only want to see place 2 - 6. I hope you can tell me how I am able to do it. People can have the same amount of points. Place User #1 and User #2 got the same amount and so I need 6 rows not 5, if it would be easy I would use order by points and limit

The output should look like:

```
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| Username(varchar) | Points(integer)     | Rank              |
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| User #1           |                 900 |                 2 |
| User #2           |                 900 |                 2 |
| User #3           |                 810 |                 3 |
| User #4           |                 800 |                 4 |
| User #5           |                 790 |                 5 |
| User #6           |                 750 |                 6 |
+-------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is really too simple. What about going to google, typing in *mysql select range* and reading the official documentation? Have you tried *any* research of your own?

Comment: What's the desired output?

Comment: i am able to google and use the search function. and i can use limit etc. but I want a ranking like a league but like in the example User #1 and User #2 got the same amount, I want to put them in a row. I want 5 rows with unique points otherwise i would do LIMIT x,y and a order by

Comment: i edited my post sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using MySQL user-defined variables to calculate "rank", assigning the same "rank" value to "ties" for points.

```
  SELECT r.username
       , r.points
       , r.rank
    FROM ( SELECT t.username
                , @rank := IF(t.points=@prev_points,@rank,@rank+1) AS rank
                , @prev_points := t.points AS points
             FROM mytable t
            CROSS
             JOIN ( SELECT @rank := 0, @prev_points := NULL ) i 
            ORDER BY t.points DESC, t.username DESC
         ) r
   WHERE r.rank BETWEEN 2 AND 6
   ORDER BY r.points DESC, r.username DESC
```

Original answer to original

You can use a `LIMIT` clause in combination with an `ORDER BY`.

For example:

```
  SELECT t.username, t.points
    FROM mytable t
   ORDER BY t.points DESC, t.username DESC
   LIMIT 4,6
```

In this example, the LIMIT clause is saying "skip the first four rows and return the next six rows".  So, this would return rows starting with the fifth row, up through the tenth row.

Comment: the problem is sometimes people can have the same amount of points and I want them in one row. So when I want 5 places and 2 people got the same amount of places, I need 6 rows from the table

Comment: @TobiasHH: This comment really looks more like information about your question, not a comment related to my answer. Please consider using the "edit" feature to add this information to your question. Others may not read the comments on my answer, and this looks to be an important part of the specification.